# Python regex for float or int while not splitting the float into two floats

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to pull data from a file that can either be an int or a float. I've found this regex that will pull these two types from the file `(\d+(\.\d+)?)`, but the problem I'm having with it is that it's splitting the floats into two.

```
>>> import re
>>> line = "(gr_line (start 218.948 126.111) (end 218.948 143.637) (angle 90) (layer Edge.Cuts) (width 0.1) (tstamp 53D2B530))"
>>>
>>> print re.findall(r'\(start (\d+(\.\d+)?) (\d+(\.\d+)?)\)', line)
[('218.948', '.948', '126.111', '.111')]
>>>
```

The purpose of this is to get the starting coordinates which are defined by (start n n), but as you can see, it's taking 218.948 and splitting it into `218.948` and `.948`. Same issue with `126.111`.

If the input string has an int in the starting brackets, I get the following:

```
>>> line = "(gr_line (start 218.948 126) (end 218.948 143.637) (angle 90) (layer Edge.Cuts) (width 0.1) (tstamp 53D2B530))"
>>> print re.findall(r'\(start (\d+(\.\d+)?) (\d+(\.\d+)?)\)', line)
[('218.948', '.948', '126', '')]
>>>
```

The issue here is the added empty index - not a huge problem, but a little inconvenient.

How can I format my regex so it captures either a float and return that float, or an int and return that int.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're capturing and saving two groupings with `(\d+(\.\d+)?)`

Try this:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

That will only save the grouping from the entire float.

Comment: This will match number from `(tstamp 53D2B530))` as well. where is parenthesis check?

Comment: @user3218114:  This is just a tweak for the part that matches the individual numbers.  If you plug this back into the full regex, which matches *two* numbers separated by a space, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

`print re.findall("\d+\.\d+|(?<=angle\s)\d+", line)`

`['218.948', '126.111', '218.948', '143.637', '90', '0.1']`

Not sure from the fact you are using findall but this finds 1 or more digits followed by a `.` followed by 1 or more digits "or" (which is represented by the `|`) one or more digits so either floats or integers

Comment: You can give some explanation why this is the solution?

Comment: `re.findall("\d+\.\d+|\d+",line)` explanation: `\d+` means to look for 1 or more digit (0-9), `\.` is to escape the `.`, otherwise it's treated as a wildcard, `|` means logical OR. So knowing these 3 things you can see its a 1 or more digits followed by 1 or more digits OR 1 or more digits.